# How to display "Pending for review post count" on front end

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing for a custom spinet to display "Pending Post Count" on front end at the user's page, need to show the pending posts counts for that particular user who is already logged in.

```
$pending_posts = wp_count_posts()->pending;
```

using this we can get overall pending post count but i need to display the counts of the particular user who is logged in.

The result should be like

```
Dear user! "10" Posts are pending for review
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show what you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the number of posts pending:

```
$number_pending_post = count(get_posts( array('author' => get_current_user_id(), 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'pending')));
```

You can then echo it:

```
echo 'Dear user! '.$number_pending_post.' Posts are pending for review';
```

Watch out for get_current_user_id(), it will return 0 if the user is not logged in. You can wrap this around the condition of is_user_logged_in()

Comment: Great! it works fine, thanks for the support Nick :)